# How do you show the series $\sum\frac{\sin(1/{n!})}{\cos({1}/{n!})}$ converges?

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

How do you show the series $\sum\frac{\sin(1/{n!})}{\cos({1}/{n!})}$ converges?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You may use, as $n \to \infty$,
$$
\frac{\sin(1/{n!})}{\cos({1}/{n!})} \sim \frac1{n!}.
$$

Comment: You mean use the limit comparison test?

Comment: Before I try to show those two sequences are asymptotic, can you let me know if it's going to be easy or difficult to do that?

Comment: @GregoryGrant Yes, the comparison test.

Comment: @GregoryGrant You may use the classical fact that $$\lim_{x \to 0}\frac{\tan x}x=1$$

Comment: @GregoryGrant You are welcome!

Answer (score 5):

$\sin(x) < x$ for all $x > 0$ and $\cos(x) > \cos(1)$ for all $0 < x < 1$, and now use the comparison test!

Comment: Thanks, I wish I could accept everybody's answer, but I'll accept the other one because he posted first.  But both answers were helpful.